# Android Tab Fragment Search Functionality

Tags: android, android-fragments, search, android-recyclerview

am working on an app with three Tabs with a search function on the toolbar, then am fetching data from SQLite and populating a recycler view the Data,  i have tried to add a search filter to it also but, it doesnt work Below is my Code .. Any Help will Be appreciated Below is my Code for the Adapter and TabFragment for the filter

```
    private ArrayList<books> book = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<books> contactListFiltered;
    List<View>itemViewList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<books> contactList;
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, booker, time;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            booker = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.body);
            time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);

        }
    }


    public MoviesAdapter(List<books> book) {
        this.book = (ArrayList<books>) book;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.books, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        books movie = book.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.booker.setText(movie.getBody());
        holder.time.setText(formatDate(books.getTimestamp()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (book == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return book.size();
    }

    private String formatDate(String dateStr) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = fmt.parse(dateStr);
            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
            return fmtOut.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }
        return "";
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    contactListFiltered = contactList;
                } else {
                    List<books> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (books row : contactList) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getBody().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    contactListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = contactListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                contactListFiltered = (ArrayList<books>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

And here is my Tab Fragment Code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        if (searchManager != null) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                    .getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        }
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // listening to search query text change
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when query submitted
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
             recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
             Toast.makeText(getContext(),"the search is on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

/// tell the recycler there is a different data to display
               mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when text is changed
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
               recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

/// tell the recycler there is a different data to display
               mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: contactList  should have all the book list but currently it's empty and no where it's assigned

Comment: how do i do that ?